# highcharts - add series into graph after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

i got graph by highcharts. Here is the series i got there.

```
series: [{
                name: 'Математика',
                data: [<?php echo $mathFirst; ?>, <?php echo $mathSecond; ?>, <?php echo $mathThird; ?>, <?php echo $mathFourth; ?>, <?php echo $mathFifth; ?>]
            }, {
                name: 'Программирование',
                data: [<?php echo $programmingFirst; ?>, <?php echo $programmingSecond; ?>, <?php echo $programmingThird; ?>, <?php echo $programmingFourth; ?>, <?php echo $programmingFifth; ?>]
            }, {
                name: 'Английский язык',
                data: [<?php echo $englishFirst; ?>, <?php echo $englishSecond; ?>, <?php echo $englishThird; ?>, <?php echo $englishFourth; ?>, <?php echo $englishFifth; ?>]
            }, {
                name: 'История',
                data: [<?php echo $historyFirst; ?>, <?php echo $historySecond; ?>, <?php echo $historyThird; ?>, <?php echo $historyFourth; ?>, <?php echo $historyFifth; ?>]
            }, {
                name: 'Все предметы',
                data: [<?php echo $middleFirst; ?>, <?php echo $middleSecond; ?>, <?php echo $middleThird; ?>, <?php echo $middleFourth; ?>, <?php echo $middleFifth; ?>]
            }]
```

And i got a select.

```
<select>
        <option value="all">Все предметы</option>
        <option value="math">Математика</option>
        <option value="programming">Программирование</option>
        <option value="english">Английский язык</option>
        <option value="history">История</option>
    </select>
```

When clicking on any option, it should add an serie into graph with some values. How can i do that?

Comment: Do you have code you have tried?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for finding answers to questions that you can't answer because of a difficulty. See [about](http://stackoverflow.com/about). You need to have attempted to have answered your question. Have you read the documentation?

Comment: You could take a look at Series.addPoint() http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series and think how can you apply it

Comment: I tried.. but there is an error - chart is undefined. Is there a way add series without using JSON?

Comment: How do you use addPoint / addSeries. Have you any live example, or full code?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick example of adding data from the `<select>` element's `onChange` event:

```
// the select handler
$('#select').change(function() {
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
    someData = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++){
        someData.push(Math.random() * 250);
    }
    chart.addSeries({
        data: someData
    });
});
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4gpj9/).